# Oracle full join "ON" condition and "AND" clause

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

Here is the query :

```
select *
from Table1 tb1 FULL JOIN Table2
     tb2
     on tb1.party_number = tb2.party_number  // returns 100 results
```

if i modify the query to add another condition like following:

```
select *
from Table1 tb1 FULL JOIN
     Table2 tb2
     on tb1.party_number = tb2.party_number AND 
        1=0
```

My understanding is that it should return 0 results , but it still returns 100 results same as the first one . Thing i dont understand is , what is the significance the clause after AND .

Comment: Do you know what `full join` does?  This results is not at all surprising.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah  , i understand the FULL JOIN part of it , should return records from both tables , but how does the AND 1=0 is interpreted ?  Like a where clause condition ?  in this case its just discarded

Comment: Learn what outer joins return: rows from inner join on the condition plus for left/right/full join unmatched left/right/both table rows extended by nulls. Your on condition is `tb1.party_number = tb2.party_number AND 1=0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AND 1 = 0` makes the `on` condition always evaluate to false.

As a result, you will get all the rows from table1 with `NULL` values for the columns from table2, along with all the rows from table2 with `NULL` values for the columns from table1.

I'm not sure what the real use of this is.  `union all` is usually a better way to get this sort of result.

That the results get the same number of rows is evidence -- but not conclusive evidence -- that there are no matches.